# highcharts disable motion - set fixed chart

Tags: highcharts

Highcharts paints the chart as the page loads. For example when a simple bar chart is loaded, columns are painted on progressively.

Is there a way to disable this? I just want to chart as it is. No movements. I tried to set animation to false. But it does not work.

Jake He

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial animation is hidden under a different "animation" option:

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            animation: false
        }
    },
```

Here's a JSFiddle using that option: http://jsfiddle.net/troygizzi/3w7noceq/

It was based on this one: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/VqruM/